# Ionic 2 HTTP Request Post not working

Tags: http, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to post data to my server, but I get a 400 Error when executing. The same request works when using get. (the post request is used for a post function and I tried the get request with a get function so that is not an issue)
This is my code:

```
  var json = 
  {
    "test":"asdf"
  }

  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  this.http.post("http://192.168.0.103:3000/testPost",json,headers)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  data =>{
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Can you try `JSON.stringify(json)` as the second parameter and send it?

Comment: I can see that in your code you are passing `headers` instead you should be passing `options` as 3rd parameter. Changing that should resolve issue!

Comment: Thank you!
Adding the JSON.stringify fixed my issue.

Comment: Looks like its more of how you are expecting the value on your server side